# extract 1st line from a text with special pattern using regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string

```
set text {tools show stats 
Resource Manager info at 023 h 06/01/20 09:14:16.105:

Hardware Resource Usage #1, abc iom-32-100g, Pipe #0:
                                 |   Total   | Allocated |    Free    
  -------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------
            stat vale abc/ghj(0) |        256|          0|        256
            stat vale abc/ghj(1) |        256|          0|        256

                   new Statistic |    Count    
---------------------------------+-------------
                           first |         0
                          seconds|         0

                      third info |    Count    
                           fourth|         0
                           fifth |       125

     Forwarding Table Statistics |   Used /  Free  /  Max  /  Reject  
---------------------------------+-----------------------------------
              third stat Entries |      2 /  36856 /  36864
                      Important  |      1 /  13133 /  13136 / 0
                fifth entry < 56 |      1 /   5743 /   5744 / 0
                sixth entry > 5 |      0 /    112 /    112 / 0

Service manager resources
-------------------------
Total count:           2/  3072
Total info:            2/   401

ABC Group Statistics |   Used /  Free  / Max
---------------------------------+-----------------------
              Entries |      0 /    256 / 256
}
```

I have to extract

```
1. Important  |      1 /  13133 /  13136 / 0
2. fifth entry < 56 |      1 /   5743 /   5744 / 0
```

both can be done separetly
I'm using the following regex in tcl to extract the same

```
1. regexp -nocase -line -- {^Important.*} $text match
2. regexp -nocase -line -- {^fifth entry \< 56.*} $text match
```

its not working, can someone help here ?

Comment: Just remove `^` anchor. Or add `[[:space:]]*` after `^`.

Comment: It worked.
`^` is used to mark start of line. How come it is not required here ?

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129986/3832970) with explanations and online demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have whitespace before the matches, the lines are indented, so you need to match the whitespace, say with `[[:space:]]*` that matches both regular spaces and tabs.

Or, just remove `^` if you do not need to match at the start of the line. `^` matches a position at the start of  a line.

To "exclude" it from the match, *capture* the text you need without the initial whitespaces using a pair of round brackets.

You may use

```
regexp -nocase -line -- {^[[:space:]]*(Important.*)} $text - match1
regexp -nocase -line -- {^[[:space:]]*(fifth entry < 56.*)} $text - match2
```

See the [Tcl online demo](https://ideone.com/EIVcjm)

Note you do not have to escape `<` if you want to match a literal `<` char.

**Details**

- `^`  - start of a  line (here, due to `-line`)
- `[[:space:]]*` - any 0  or more whitespaces
- `(Important.*)` - Capturing group 1: `Important` and any 0 or more chars other than line break chars.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. `regexp -nocase -line -- {^Important.*} $text match`

You have spaces before `Important`, so you should add them to your expression like thus:

```
regexp -nocase -line -- {^ *Important.*} $text match
```

> 2. `regexp -nocase -line -- {^fifth entry \< 56.*} $text match`

Same here (and `<` does not need to be escaped):

```
regexp -nocase -line -- {^ *fifth entry < 56.*} $text match
```